# How to assertThat superclass list equal to subclass matcher using hamcrest and mockito

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I am trying to do the following.

```
final Matcher<SuperClass> matcher1 = Matchers.hasProperty("a", equalTo("b"));
final Matcher<SuperClass> matcher2 = Matchers.hasProperty("c", equalTo("d"));
final Matcher<SuperClass> matchers = Matchers.allOf(matcher1, matcher2);

List<SubClass> list = someStuff();

assertThat(list, everyItem(matchers));
```

I am getting a compilation error on the assert line, is there any easy way to get rid of this.

Comment: What's the compilation error?

Comment: The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type MatcherAssert is not applicable for the arguments (List<SubClass>, Matcher<Iterable<SuperClass>>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
@Test public void yourTest() {
    final Matcher<SuperClass> matcher1 = Matchers.hasProperty("a", equalTo("b"));
    final Matcher<SuperClass> matcher2 = Matchers.hasProperty("c", equalTo("d"));
    final Matcher<SuperClass> matchers = Matchers.allOf(matcher1, matcher2);
    List<SubClass> list = someStuff();
    // Note cast to raw type here, corresponding to the suppressed warnings.
    assertThat(list, (Matcher) everyItem(matchers));
}
```

#### Option 2:

```
// These are all of type Matcher<SubClass> instead.
final Matcher<SubClass> matcher1 = Matchers.hasProperty("a", equalTo("b"));
final Matcher<SubClass> matcher2 = Matchers.hasProperty("c", equalTo("d"));
final Matcher<SubClass> matchers = Matchers.allOf(matcher1, matcher2);
List<SubClass> list = someStuff();
assertThat(list, everyItem(matchers));
```

**Why?** Java's generics handling is too clever for Hamcrest. `everyItem(matchers)` will return a `Matcher<Iterable<SuperClass>>`, but you don't have an `Iterable<SuperClass>`, you have an `Iterable<SubClass>`. It would all be fine if you actually had your Matcher methods produce a `Matcher<Iterable<? extends SuperClass>>`, but it's nearly impossible for you to convince Java that your `matcher1` and `matcher2` are compatible with one another.

Answer (score 0):

Generics.

The problem with your code is that you try to assert that a list with type `List<SubClass>` matches every item of a matcher with type `Matcher<SuperClass>`.

Even though `SuperClass` extends `SubClass`, the `assertThat` method requires the two to be the same.

So if you can coerce your `someStuff()` method to return a list of of `SuperClass`, you should be home free. I.e. something like this

```
    List<SuperClass> list = someStuff();
    assertThat(list, everyItem(matchers));
```

would get rid of the compilation error.